# Should I select a drawer slide slightly shorter or slightly longer than the drawer?

Tags: drawers

If my drawer is 17.25" inches deep, but the space is 18" deep, would I be better using an 18" or 16" bottom mount soft closing slide? The reason the drawer is 17.25" is because there is a brace at the top of the desk that prevents an 18" drawer from going all the way in. Thanks for any help.

The Everbilt Bottom Mount Soft Close Cabinet Drawer Slides. Model # 9280531

Comment: What manufacturer and model number of drawer slides are you planning to use?

Comment: The Everbilt Bottom Mount Soft Close Cabinet Drawer Slides. Model # 9280531

Comment: Thanks. That slide does look like it is not dependent on the drawer box depth, as some bottom mounts slides are. The only limitation in a shorter slide would be less opening space on the drawer. These slides aren't full-extension, they lose 3-ish inches of opening ability by design.

Comment: If I were to use the 16" slide, it would be a 1 1/4" short. My concern with using the 18" is that if the drawer can't go back the last 3/4" due to the brace, would that interfere with the soft close function?

Comment: I found this slide model at Home Depot's website. The link to the instructions PDF does show that the soft-close part does not extend past the back of the slide. The Home Depot specs say the slide is 18 1/2" deep. If that will not fit into your space, then you'll have to use the 16" slide.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter slide, mounted toward the front, would work fine but would limit the opening distance a bit.

I would use whichever of the two gave me the easiest secure mounting option.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if the soft close element would work if the drawer came up 3/4" short on an 18" slide.

Comment: Yes in that case I would definitely use the shorter slide.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Patrick, if you're not sure, then the manufacturer is the _perfect_ source of info! Hit up their website, _somewhere_ there will be a "contact us" link and you can ask them to be 100% certain that this is the correct answer. (Not doubting Jimmy, just confirming that this is correct.) If it turns out to be correct, come back and give it a check mark!